# Base64: Java encoding file csv

Tags: java, base64, export-to-csv

I wanted to generate a csv file and then attach it in an email.
it all works very well, except that the contents of the file generate
contains special characters as below:

```
¬í t ›Ã‰vÃ©nementId;DÃ©butÃ‰vÃ©nement;FinÃ‰vÃ©nement;DescriptionÃ‰vÃ©nement
232750;20/03/201408:30;20/03/201412:30;
233160;17/05/201412:50;17/05/201414:20;
```

below a piece of code:

```
String dataString= "id;date1;date2;description
 232750;20/03/201408:30;20/03/201412:30;
 233160;17/05/201412:50;17/05/201414:20;"

public byte[] covertObjecttoByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
byte[] bytes = null;
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytArrOutStr = null;
 ObjectOutputStream objOutStrem = null;
  try {
     bytArrOutStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     objOutStrem.writeObject(obj);
     objOutStrem.flush();
      bytes = bytArrOutStr.toByteArray();
    } finally {
      if (objOutStrem != null) {
        objOutStrem.close();
        }
        if (bytArrOutStr != null) {
            bytArrOutStr.close();
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}


 byte[] dataByte = covertObjecttoByteArray(data);
 String dataBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(dataByte);
```

I use this variable "dataBase64" to put the file attached in the xml structure like this

```
<attachment FileName="Fiche.csv">
 JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggMTIyOC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+&#13;
 PnN0cmVhbQp4nMVYTW/bRhAdQDee8uF8FTGwQA3HLVKau+QuKaCnQpEVV4VNSbZTxDk1TYCiAtxc&#13;
 +gP6xzsz5JKMLO2uKNeFIIkUl5o3b97MzvCv6KdFlBpRJEYsPkZvFlEZKXFKv0qR4Is+i0yJxTI6&#13;
 HkshE7H4FB19t/iD1rZLEvHbcvX0/Qf8/sh/hzfi68tn+9vKyiQuBL15iVIiH+ZCayl+kFp8+T36&#13;
<attachment/>
```

My question is how to solve the problem of encoding

Comment: So... What's the question? Decoding messes up?

Comment: i can decode the message, but I get a file with special characters
How can i specifie UTF8 encoding

Comment: You never instantiate `ObjectOutputStream`. How the code is even working? :O

Comment: I did not understand.
I did not put all the code, but I'm garatil it works ;)

Comment: another simple example:

HttpServletResponse presponse;
presponse.setContentType(application/download; charset=utf-8));
presponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + param.get("fileName") + "." + param.get("extension") + "\"");
ServletOutputStream lout = presponse.getOutputStream();
lout.write((byte[]) Utilities.covertObjecttoByteArray(data));

but I get a file with special characters